# Not able to get location with Service (LocationManager)

Tags: java, android, service, gps, locationmanager

i am in real trouble here. Trying to get lat and lon with a background service every 3 sec but i am only able to get some data written when i click send lat and lon in extended controls of the emulator , so both phone and emulator are not working. Here is my code below, it would be awesome if someone could help me. Thanks!

Service

```
public class GPSService extends Service {


    private static final String TAG = "GpsService";
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
                i.putExtra("latExtra",location.getLatitude());
                i.putExtra("lonExtra",location.getLongitude());
                sendBroadcast(i);
                Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: extras lat lon"+location.getLatitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: DISABLED");
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        locationManager =(LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria c = new Criteria();
        String provider =locationManager.getBestProvider(c,true);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: bestProvider "+provider);

        //noinspection MissingPermission
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,2000,0,locationListener);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (locationManager != null){
            Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: Location manager nije null i brisem");
            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
    private final String TAG = "Main";
    ...
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReciever;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //setStatusBarTranslucent(false);


        if(!runtimePermisions()){
            startLocationUpdate();}
...

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //stopService();
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //REQUEST PERMISSION
                    Log.i(TAG, "onClick: NO PERMISION");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onClick: got permision");
                }
...
    }
    public void startLocationUpdate(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,GPSService.class);
        startService(i);
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdate: Pokrenuo sam service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (broadcastReciever == null){
            broadcastReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    lat = (Double) intent.getExtras().get("latExtra");
                    lon = (Double) intent.getExtras().get("lonExtra");

                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: lat lon "+lat+" "+lon);
                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReciever,new IntentFilter("location_update"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (broadcastReciever!=null){
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReciever);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 100) {
                if (grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    startLocationUpdate();
                }else{
                    runtimePermisions();}
            }

    }


    private boolean runtimePermisions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,

            },100);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.digiart.yoweather">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme"></activity>
        <service android:name=".Gps.GPSService"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Again... Any help would be great! THANKS :D

Comment: For me, need to wait a few seconds before phone can get the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As K. Sopheak said, it can take a while to get the location. From the documentation:

> It may take a while to receive the first location update. If an immediate location is required, applications may use the getLastKnownLocation(String) method.

So, you could try getting the last known location using `getLastKnownLocation(String)` when the service is started and, assuming it exists, broadcast it in the same way you would a location update. Bear in mind, though, that the last known location could be out of date. Depending on what you're using the location for this may or may not be acceptable.

Also, as an aside, a couple of thoughts:

1. You said 3 seconds, but the code uses 2,000 milliseconds - was that just a typo?
2. The frequency of location updates is a *minimum* time - you are not guaranteed to get updates that often. As per the documentation:

   > The location update interval can be controlled using the minTime parameter. The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other applications.
3. Is there any particular reason you need location updates at such a high frequency? Obtaining a location can be battery intensive, particularly given that you are requesting FINE as well as COARSE location permissions, so requesting it so frequently could place an enormous drain on device battery life. This is particularly so given that the code is running in a service and will therefore continue to run even when the application is in the background or the user is in an activity which does not require location data. Again, from the documentation:

   > Choosing a sensible value for minTime is important to conserve battery life. Each location update requires power from GPS, WIFI, Cell and other radios. Select a minTime value as high as possible while still providing a reasonable user experience. If your application is not in the foreground and showing location to the user then your application should avoid using an active provider (such as NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER), but if you insist then select a minTime of 5 * 60 * 1000 (5 minutes) or greater. If your application is in the foreground and showing location to the user then it is appropriate to select a faster update interval.
4. Google recommends using the [Google Play services location APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) instead of the Android framework location APIs:

   > The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app. If you are currently using the Android framework location APIs, you are strongly encouraged to switch to the Google Play services location APIs as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, yep it was just i typo i changed it to 2sec to check it. My question is shouldn't locationChanged fire some data even if it is null? Basically i just need to get one single location so i can pull my weather data and thats it, and on refresh button to check the location again. I just ran out of options because anything i try will not work and i am having huge amounts of trouble with this for the last 6 days. I dont know about google play services because sometimes the user will not have them turned on. Do you have any simple solutions for my problem?Thanks again